# How to find Either array having value or not in android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm using `AutoCompleteTextView` in my current project.

**Details:**

When user types data in `AutoCompleteTextView` then i'm  checking either that data in arrayList or not!!

for this i tried below code but it's not working it's showing No data available in array.

Can anyone help to resolve this!?

**What I want:**

When user type one letter if that match with arrayList then i have to show arrayList having this letter.

example if user types: M or Me or Ve; then it's show array-list having this data.

**Here's my code:-**

```
 String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury","Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
            "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};

autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                Log.i("--------->1", "onTextChanged is +"+autoCompleteTextView.getText());

                if (Arrays.asList(planets).contains(autoCompleteTextView.getText())) {

                    Log.i("--------->1", "Having");

                }else{

                    Log.i("--------->1", "No");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                Log.i("--------->1", "afterTextChanged is +"+autoCompleteTextView.getText());

                if (Arrays.asList(planets).contains(autoCompleteTextView.getText())) {

                    Log.i("--------->1", "Having");

                }else{

                    Log.i("--------->1", "No");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString().... just edit that

Comment: please clearly read my requirement and that's not  my requirement

Comment: AutoComplete implementation your using is wrong - Ref :https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/12/android-autocompletetextview-custom-arrayadapter-sqlite.html

Answer (score 0):

You can test this below:

Arrays.asList(planets).contains(autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString())

Also, no need of writing the code in afterTextChanged(Editable s).

onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) is pretty much enough.

Comment: even one or two letters match then also need to show arraylist having this data

Answer (score 0):

This is **NOT** how you use AutoCompleteTextView before trying to hack a view, read its documentation of how it *should* be used:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Answer (score 0):

try this solution :
in listSearchedPlanets you will get the list of planets which contains the string entered in AutoCompleteTextView.

```
        autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            List<String> listPlanets = Arrays.asList(planets);

            List<String> listSearchedPlanets = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < listPlanets.size(); i++) {

                if (listPlanets.get(i).contains(autoCompleteTextView.getText())) {
                    listSearchedPlanets.add(listPlanets.get(i));
                }

            }

            if (listSearchedPlanets.size() > 0) {
                Log.i("--------->1", "Having");
            }else {
                Log.i("--------->1", "No");
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```